# Ker$\phi$ is isomorphic to and not isomorphic to?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the group homomorphism $\phi:M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(A)=Tr(A)$. Then the kernel of $\phi$ is not isomorphic to

(a)$M_{2}\mathbb{R}/\{A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}):\phi(A)=0\}$

(b)$\mathbb{R^{2}}$

(c)$\mathbb{R^{3}}$

(d)$Gl_{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Here the correct answer is given as option (a). I am not getting this how they got that. And if option (a) is correct then the kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and $Gl_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. But how the kernel will be isomorphic to this three sets.

Since the kernel is the set $\{\begin{bmatrix}a&&b\\c&&-a\end{bmatrix}\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}):a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$, for option $c$, I can define the isomorphism map as $f\Big(\begin{bmatrix}a&&b\\c&&-a\end{bmatrix}\Big)=(a,b,c)$. But what should be the map for the other two options, I am not getting and why the option a is correct, that also I want to know.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The correct answer is (d), which is not abelian. (a) and (c) are isomorphic as real vector spaces, hence as abelian groups. And they are both isomorphic as rational vector spaces to (b), so they are all isomorphic as abelian groups.

Comment: But can u help me in understanding why a and c are isomorphic as real vectorspace.

Comment: They are definitely **not** isomorphic as *real* vector spaces, but they are as *rational* vector spaces (this is by no means obvious and uses the fact that $\Bbb R$ is infinite dimensional as $\Bbb Q$-vector space)

Comment: Yeah, I misspoke (a) is dimension 1 over the reals, (c) is 3 dimensional. But they are all continuum-dimensional over the rationals.